# Removing app from Settings (Sign in with Apple - Revoke API for account deletion)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-sign-in

Apple Settings shows which apps you are currently using with Sign in with Apple. It is located in `Settings -> Password & Security -> Apps Using Apple ID`. This is how it looks:

[image]

My question is, does this Apple API `appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke` ([API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens)) remove the app from Apple Settings as shown above? I want this API to remove it from Apple Settings but the documentation is not very clear if it does.

Note: this is in regards to Apple's account deletion requirement as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app).

Comment: Just run the curl command in terminal to verify

Comment: @JEL, do you find the solution, i have tried the API but nothing changed, the token is still authrized

Comment: @jimwan I haven't. Thanks for letting me know the API doesn't work. I guess there is no way if the API doesn't work

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @ursan526 I have not found a solution

Answer (score 0):

The Apple API [token/revoke](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens) does remove the Apple ID binding with the App under the [Sign in with Apple settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426).

For the summary on the API's usage, please refer to the great answer written by *zangw* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656672/12230505).